# Proving a limit Epsilon Delta definition

Tags: real-analysis

How do I find and prove the limit of the following function using the epsilon delta definition.

$$\lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{2+\sin x}{3-\cos x}x$$

Comment: Hint: You have $\bigg|\frac{2+\sin x}{3-\cos x} x\bigg| \leq \frac{3|x|}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

We know $\frac{1}{4}\leq |\frac{2+\sin x}{3-\cos x}|\leq \frac{3}{2} $.

Then for any $\epsilon>0$,  there exist $\delta=\frac{2}{3}\epsilon$ such that if $|x|<\delta$, we have 
\begin{equation}
|\frac{2+sinx}{3-cosx}x|< \frac{3}{2} \times \delta =\frac{3}{2}\times \frac{2}{3}\epsilon=\epsilon
\end{equation}

This means 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{2+sinx}{3-cosx}x=0
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Firstly we assume the limit is  0, now we need to show:

$\forall\epsilon \gt0 ,\, \exists\delta\gt 0 :|x-0|\lt\delta\Rightarrow|\frac{2+\sin x}{3-\cos x}x-0|\lt\epsilon$

Now:

$|\frac{2+\sin x}{3-\cos x }x - 0 |=|\frac{2+\sin x}{3-\cos x}x|\leq\frac {3}{2}|x|\lt\frac {3}{2}\delta$

So we pick $\delta=\frac { 2 } { 3 } \epsilon$ then if $|x|\lt \delta$

$\Rightarrow |\frac{2+\sin x}{3-\cos x }x - 0 |\lt\frac {3}{2}\delta=\epsilon$

Thus the limit is 0